Can't delete overriden collection
I am struggling for hours with this... I added a linked collection, tried to override (content and/or selected), now I want to delete the collection and it's not possible. Tried every clearing options from all levels, and I still can't delete...

I must admit don't know why this overriding thing is soooo complicated. Why not letting access any custom property by default directly from a collection ?? I guess there must be rason but still... Complicated :(

Select collection. and right click and press unlink.
In my case. it works.


Thanks ! It works.
